# SMB3/2 Server with Signing/Encryption as testserver

Tags: automated-tests, smb, smbj

Is there a test suite for SMB3/2 available on the market that provides me with an SMB server that provides me with all possible combinations (signing / encryption etc.) to check if our software adapts correctly to all possible constellations?

Background is that here are many SMB implementations on the market (Windows, NetAPP, OpenSMB) which all behave slightly different and this often leads to errors.

How is that tested by other firms? Did they wrote all her own tools?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day :-)

I need from other guys with experience in that topic some brainstorming by this ticket.